# Creating a singly linked list with 2 structures in C

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct, linked-list

I am working with these two structures, the first holds the employee information while the second holds the list information:

```
typedef struct ListNodeTag{
  int idNumber;
  struct ListNodeTag *next;
} Employee;

typedef Employee Item;

typedef struct {
  int size;
  Item *head;
} List;
```

When the program starts, the list is initialized with this function:  The list is declared in my main as **List L**; and is called like this: **Initialize (&L);**

```
void Initialize (List *L) {
  L->size = 0;
  L->head = NULL;
}
```

From here, I am able to get the list size set to 0 correctly.

I then proceed to add Employee's to the list with these two functions.  The first (EmployeeCreation) creates the employee, while the second (Insert) takes it and inserts it into the list.  The employee is declared in my main as **Employee E**; and called like this      **EmployeeCreation(XXX, &E);**

```
void EmployeeCreation (int idNumber, Employee *E) {   
  E->idNuber = idNumber;
  E->next = NULL;  
}

void Insert (Item X, int position, List *L) {
  int i;
  Item *currentPtr,*previousPtr;
  if(L->head == NULL)
  L->head = &X;
  else{
    currentPtr = L->head;
    for(i=0;i<position;i++){
      previousPtr = currentPtr;
      currentPtr = currentPtr->next;
    }
  previousPtr->next = &X;
  X.next = currentPtr; 
  L->size = L->size + 1;
  }  
}
```

When run with a test file of 4 ID's. the first is read in correctly and saved to the list.  The second, replaces the first, and the length of the list increases by 1 (I understand this part).  After this, the program Seg Faults.  Where would this error be occurring in my program?  Even if the **Insert** function wants to override a position already occupied I think it should make room just fine and stitch in the new location.

Comment: This will not compile - as the data structure `Employee` does not have a member `name`. So why give code that actually compiles?

Comment: I have removed that, I deleted some of the code for simplicity.

Comment: What is Item in the Insert function?

Comment: Item has been type defed to the Employee struct

Comment: @user2225940 - There is simplicity but removing code so that it does not even compile is not letting us with a fighting chance.

Comment: As you are in the `C` world read up about `malloc`

Comment: The code I have provided does compile with GCC.  Also, are you suggesting that this is a malloc issue within the Insert function?

Comment: @user2225940 - Now that you have edited the question it may compile. Not given it a go yet. But do you understand the difference between the stack and the heap? somewhere along the line you need to use `malloc`

Comment: Thanks, and I do get the difference.  I just can't see right now where it would be where I add a malloc

Comment: The insert function has its arguments on the stack. You want X onto the heap. i.e. `malloc`. Now do you understand the difference and what code changes are required?

Comment: I am not able to change the function call to a `Item *` so this X must be kept static.  I'm looking for a way to copy the information passed in from X into a pointer and then tack that pointer onto the list.

Comment: @user2225940 - Even your function EmployeeCreation is incorect. Where does `grade` come from and `idNumber` is not even used. Is this more simplification?

Comment: It is, I have corrected this and there should be no more errors.  I'm in quite a predicament and working on a few things at once right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
void Insert (Item X, int position, List *L) {
  int i;
  Item *currentPtr,*previousPtr;
  Item *newX = malloc(sizeof(Item);
  newX->idNunmber - X.idNumber;
  newX->next = NULL;

  if (L->head == NULL) {
      L->head = newX;
  } else {
    currentPtr = L->head;
    previousPtr = NULL;
    for(i=0;currentPtr!= NULL && i<position;i++) {
      previousPtr = currentPtr;
      currentPtr = currentPtr->next;
    }

    newX->next = currentPtr;
    previousPtr->next = newX; 
    L->size +=1;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help, however I am getting a seg fault when I try to add my second employee to the list.

Comment: I've been able to determine it crashes at the start of the for loop, any ideas as to why that is?

Comment: How is L initialised?

Comment: The initialize function is written above and L is initialized as `List L;`

Comment: I believe you're code is fine, I have error else where in my code that need fixing.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the address of a local variable (`item X`) to `L->head`

`L->head = &X;`

When you exit from `Insert`, `L->head` points to garbage because `X` is no longer accesible, to fix this you can:

```
void Insert (Item *X, int position, List *L) {
  ...
  L->head = X;
  ...  
}

Item *temp = malloc(sizeof(Item));

Insert(temp, ..., ...);
...
free(temp);
```

Comment: Removing the & will fix this?  When this is done I get an error saying incompatible types for the assignment.

Comment: Nops, when you exit from your function `item` is no longer accesible.

Comment: Instead of assigning the address of a local variable how else would I be able to move the information from the employee create to insert?

Comment: You have to pass the address of `X` to the function and remove the `&`

Comment: Is there no other method than that?  Making `Item X` `Item *X` is not close to ideal for this situation.

Comment: Why? if you want to store a pointer you have to pass a pointer

Comment: Its a requirement in order to keep these functions accessible over a variety of uses.  Would it be possible to create an Item Temp pointer and mallocing enough memory for X to it, then assign the temp pointer to X and from there to the head?

Comment: Of course, this is a possible solution, but you don't need an `Item Temp`, malloc and pass this (m)allocated pointer directly

Comment: Unfortunately making the `Item X` a pointer is unavailable no matter how much more sense it makes.  To `malloc *temp` would this do what I need: `temp = malloc(sizeof(X));`?

Comment: Yes, `temp = malloc(sizeof(X));` is what you need

Comment: And to correctly assign the values to temp I use `temp = &X;`

Answer (score 0):

In the Insert function, you could simplify this part and check --

```
else{
  currentPtr = L->head;
  for(i=0;i<position;i++){
    currentPtr = currentPtr->next;
  }
  Item *nextItm = currentPtr.next;
  currentPtr.next = &X;
  X .next = nextItm ; 
  L->size = L->size + 1;
}
```

Comment: Simplify in what way?  I thought I already had the bar minimum there to make it work.